# Почему не работает post запрос через ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Почему не работает post запрос через ajax?

```
function test(){
  $.ajax ({  
    url: "/post.php",  
    type: "POST",  
    dataType: "json",  
    data: "flag=1",  
    success: function(data){  
      if(data =='success') alert ("Данные успешно получены");}  
  });  
}
```

файл post.php:

```
<?php 
  if($_POST[flag] == 1){
    echo 'success';
  }
  $flag = $_POST[flag];
  echo $_POST[flag];
?>
```

Всё происходит на Denwer, JQuеry подключен:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[так выгладит страница post.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtayM.png)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Насколько знаю dataдолжен быть объектом. А вы просто строку передаёте

Comment: Если вы в чем-то не уверены - то уточните сначала, а не бегите писать ответ.

Comment: Не заметил, чтобы вы с первого раза дали точный совет автору.

Comment: Я и не собирался. А вы вместо того чтобы уточнить можно ли передавать строку (что можно делать), еще больше путаете автора.

Comment: И того команда success: function(alert("пришёл");) срабатывает и это хорошо, но на странице post.php пишет, что пост массив пуст, так и должно быть или это уже проблемы сервера?

Comment: Ладно, придется побыть телепатом. Как вызывается функция `test` - клик по ссылке?

Comment: в другой функции которая вызывается кликом по логическому полю

Answer (score 0):

Вы неправильно обращаетесь к элементу массива. Значение `flag` нужно взять в кавычки, так как `$_POST` это ассоциативный массив, где `flag` - это ключ. Это что относится к вашему коду.

```
<?php 
  if($_POST['flag'] == 1){
    echo 'success';
  }
  $flag = $_POST['flag'];
  echo $_POST['flag'];
?>
```

Чтобы увидеть, что находится в массиве `$_POST`, перед `if` напишите

```
var_dump($_POST);
die();
```

Comment: Я изменил как вы сказали, но это не дало каких-то результатов, почему-то.                             
 `<?php 
  if($_POST['flag'] == 1){
    echo 'success';
  }
  $flag = $_POST['flag'];
  echo $_POST['flag'];
  var_dump($_POST);
die();
?>`

Comment: `var_dump($_POST); die();` - перед `if` поставьте и смотрите что вывод

Comment: А каких результатов вы вообще ожидаете?

Comment: то что $_POST не будет пустым  @u_mulder

Comment: А на вкладке Response что выводится?

Comment: Уже максимально просто а оно почему-то не работает .`$.ajax ({
url:"post.php",
type: "POST",
data:"flag=1",
dataType: "html",
success: function(){} 
});
}` `<?php 
  if(isset($_POST['flag'] )){
    echo 'success';
  }
?>`

Comment: @u_mulder, вкладка Response???

Comment: Да, вкладка Response, через одну от вкладки Headers на вашем скрине.

Comment: выдаёт success это означает что всё работает или что?

Comment: Это дословный ответ от вашего php-скрипта

Comment: Но post масив пуст

Comment: Почему он пуст?

Comment: я перестал понимать я думал, что команда echo , будет выводить на странице php, когда я добавил var_dump($_POST);die();  теперь пишется array(1) {
  ["flag"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}

Comment: Сделайте параметр data через объект:

Answer (score 0):

Во первых. То что сказал  уважаемый @Swartex.
Во вторых передавать надо переменную с именем.

```
function test(){
  var flag = 1; //создаем переменную
  $.ajax ({  
    url: "/post.php",  
    type: "POST",  
    dataType: "html", //попробуйте так  
    data: {"flag":flag}, //имя "flag", значение flag
    success: function(data){  
      if(data =='success') alert ("Данные успешно получены");}  
  });  
}
```

Затем уже сможем ее поймать как `$_POST['flag']`
А если уж вы передаете `json` - то мне всегда казалось что надо сначала делать `json_decode`, и только потом с этими данными работать